# Change access modifier in designer file

Tags: c#, controls

Hi have a ASCX file that contains a collection of controls, mostly TextBox control. I need to access these controls via an instance of the ASCX file that I instantiate via Page.LoadControl(), which works well.

Currently, I have an extension method, that recursively finds the control by ID and then creates and instance of it's type, but this to me seams so overkill.

I know the reason I cannot go ctl.TextBox1 is because of the access modifier that gets set to protected in the .designer.cs file when I created the ascx file in VS, and changing this to public feels wrong.

I cannot create a public field for TextBox1 in acsx.cs because it already exists, and I don't want to remove the .designer.cs file, cause then everything fails.

Is there a more elegant way to change the access modifier from protected to public? I have not come across one yet.

Comment: Why dont to try add a set/get method for that control?

Comment: why didn't i think of that :$. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Add Get/Set Methods for controls which needs access instead of changing the modifiers of Designer file.